# MVC.NET HttpSessionStateWrapper - what is best usage practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, httprequest, httpcontext

We are developing large MVC project and we have an intension to use HttpSessionStateWrapper (as well as HttpRequestWrapper, HttpResponseWrapper, etc) to add extended functionalities do this objects. It would be adding session messages, additional collections, html metadata with response - stuff like that, managable from controllers and accessible in the views when needed.

I have done it in a smaller project and it gennerally worked well, except some casting issues here and there, but it can be worked around by not using wrappers outside controllers or eventually views. Every controller would be a custom controller with a code like that:

```
public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public new CustomHttpResponse Response
    {
        get
        {
            return (CustomHttpResponse)HttpContext.Response;
        }
    }

    public new CustomHttpRequestRequest
    {
        get
        {
            return (CustomHttpRequestRequest)HttpContext.Request;
        }
    }
    //etc...

}
```

ContextWrapper would be created in a custom MvcHandler. Response, request and session wrappers would be created and taken from ContextWrapper .

Is this a good policy to use wrappers to extend functionalities, or they where intended only for creating testing mocks?

Comment: How would you unit test that?

Comment: I could create a mock deriving from CustomHttpContext (and rest of CustomContext) and inject them during context creation. Testing is not an issue - the question is - is it right to use Context,Request,Response,Session wrappers to extend theirs functionality and not only for testing purposes.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to create a Mock because you're deriving from `HttpContext`, which is not mockable. If you inherit from `HttpContextBase`, that can be mocked. Granted, this doesn't answer your question - just wanted to flag it :)

Comment: I will derive from `HttpContextWrapper`, which base type is `HttpContextBase`, so creating mock is possible :) Based on answers for this question I will decide wether to extend MVC wrappers, or just use them as they are. In both cases testing is possible.